# Access nonstatic members of a static class

Tags: c#, class, static, instance

I have a static class defined as follows:

```
 public static class Classroom
  {
    public string Name;
    //other members
  }
```

How can i access the variable `Name` in another class?

Since it is a static class am not able to create an instance like this

```
Classroom ClassroomObj = new Classroom();
```

Since the `Name` is not static i cannot access it without creating an instance. then how can i access the variable?

Comment: You can't even *declare* non-static members inside a static class. That first code snippet won't compile.

Comment: Invalid code aside - Static is static and instances is instances and never the twain shall meet. You might as well say "I've got a chocolate bar in my car, how do I access it via the concept of cars?"

Comment: I think the downvoting on this question is a little harsh. This seems like a legitimate question for a newbie programmer. The OP is questioning *why* the code won't compile so help him out a little

Comment: @MattWilko but that wasn't the question. The question states "I have this class..." and then asks a *specific* question based on that false premise. There's no valid question to answer and trying to invent another question off the back of it and answer that just leads to a Q&A with no clear question and answer (i.e. poor quality content). This is exactly what the downvote button is for. It is a rating of the content, not a punishment for the user.

Comment: @AntP "There's no valid question to answer " - yes, there is one, read carefully: "how can i access the variable?".

Comment: @tomab that is an invalid question because it is based on the premise that the variable exists, which it doesn't because the code declaring it is nonsensical. The question is as valid as asking "why is the sky green?"

Comment: @AntP I think it is valid: the OP misunderstood the way `static` works. He asks something he wants to achieve; so an answer must lead him to the place where the misunderstading is.

Comment: @tomab The question is still not valid. It is based on false premises. If the asked asked "why can't I declare instance variables in a non-static class," that would be a valid question. But the asker *states* that he *has already done that*, which he can't have done. It's like saying "I just dried my hands with water; how does that work?" The question can't be answered - it is not valid. As can already be seen, attempting to answer a question that does not make sense in the first place leads to everyone inventing their own question and making different assumptions and no clear answer emerging.

Comment: @un-lucky the answers below should answer your question theoretically. But one thing is a big questionmark though: Why did you use Classroom as STATIC class? Is it because of some methods that you want to use without having to make a new instance? (that would work by just making those methods static without a need to make the class static) Or what other reason do you have there? (A static class with a property "Name" just raises my alarm signals that there is some possible thinking error there when the class was designed)

Comment: @AntP When a user is confused about how some things work, it is more confusing to burden him with valid/not valid issues about how the question should be written. So, whether it is valid or not (we still have different opininons), the goal is to help the actual issue.

Comment: @tomab and until the "actual issue" is clearly presented, the question is of poor quality and should be downvoted as such. Again, as I stated at the very beginning, votes are a rating of the *quality of content*, not a reward/punishment for a user. The only discernible question here other than what is presented is "I don't understand static classes," which is *also a poor question*. Trying to answer a broad question in a narrow context doesn't actually help anyone, especially the asker. Downvoting and being helpful are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Sounds like the two of you have a vastly different oppinion there. May I suggest there taking it to a chat to discuss it out if you want to (I myself don't see it too sharp there as I often confused can and could myself as I'm not a native speaker. And if the code doesn't compile it could be that the OP has only done some design and thought it through without compiling and stumbled over the problem at hand). But whatever the case he asked, he got answers and maybe he can explain the idea behind the static class (as its design seems flawed with a name variable in a static class).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make the variable `static` as well:

```
public static class Classroom
{
    public static string Name;
    //other members
}
```

The reason is this: your static class can be viewed as a single instance which is accessed using its name, instead of creating an instance with `new` and access it using a variable name. So any property inside this static class must have `static` as well so that it is available, again, by using the class name.

Comment: I doubt, that `Classroom` should be `static` in the context of the question: it means that there's *one and only one* classroom.

Comment: The premise of my answer was that the OP understands how objects and instances work with the help of `new` but is confused about `static`. The context does not clarify if there should be only one instance or not.

Comment: Which is exactly why the response should be to seek clarity instead of posting an answer that at best may not be appropriate and at worst may actually encourage misunderstandings and bad habits ;)

Comment: Answers should abide to the questions asked even if the questions themselves are flawed. It was asked already in comments if the OP is sure about his design as it seems flawed (in the worst case it is just a thinking example and the classroom was the first meaningful name that came to mind and thus has nothing to do with the basic idea of the static class he has in mind). So without the OP answering and clarifying which he/she didn't so far answers can only be based on the premise set by the OP. So nothing wrong with the answer and the questions ARE/WERE asked in comments so nothing more to do

Answer (score 4):

As for `static class` you can' *create its instances*:

```
  public static class MyClass {
    public static String SomeField;
    ....
  }

  // the class is static, no instances are allowed
  var o = new MyClass(); // <- Compile time error!
```

However, *non-static* (i.e. *instance*) fields *want* instance, which in case of *static class* can't be provided anyhow. That's why *non-static* fields are not allowed in the *static* classes. And so you should either change your class into *ordinal* one:

```
  // No static
  public class Classroom
  {
    public string Name;
    ... 
  }

  ...

  Classroom room = new Classroom();
  room.Name = "123";
```

Or make the `Name` being `static` as well (I doubt, however, you want the solution of that kind: it means that you have just *one* `Classroom`):

```
  public static class Classroom
  {
    // note "static"
    public static string Name;
    ... 
  }

  ...

  Classroom.Name = "123";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare instance members in a static class

Comment: @freshbm this is actually an answer because the request is impossible to achieve. What would be your answer to a question like "How to instantiate a namespace in C#?"